# Evaluating code after parsing it

Tags: python-2.7, rpy2

I'm trying to create a tool written in Python that executes R scripts (from files), injecting values into variables before executing them and reading output variables after that.

The rinterface documentation mentions the parse function, but there is no indication about how to execute the result. The C interface contains an eval function but it doesn't seem available in Python.

Here's a very basic example of what I want to do :

```
import rpy2.rinterface as ri
ri.initr()
with open('script.r', 'r') as myFile:
  script = myFile.read()
expr = ri.parse(script)

# prepare
ri.globalenv['input'] = ri.IntSexpVector((1, 2, 3, 4))

# execute
#??????????????????
# what to do here ?
#??????????????????

# fetch results
# The script is supposed to store results into a global var named 'output'
result = ri.globalenv['output']
```

Thanks

Comment: Also explanations about downvotes are always appreciated !

Comment: Drive-by downvotes should just be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways.
One is:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
base.eval(expr)
```